# Pausing timers doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: c#, timer

I wrote an application that downloads files via FTP every 10 seconds and I have the following timer's code.

```
timer3.Tick += new EventHandler(updateLogs);
timer3.Interval = (1000) * (10);
timer3.Enabled = true;
timer3.Start();
```

My updateLogs function:

```
timer3.Enabled = false;
server1_log = downloadLog("192.168.0.217", 1);
server2_log = downloadLog("192.168.0.216", 2);
server3_log = downloadLog("192.168.0.215", 3);
timer3.Enabled = true;
```

I realize that the requests may take longer than 10s and this is why I am disabling the timer before, and enabling after, calling downloadLog().

Still, after about a minute, the application freezes and the CPU usage jumps to 45+ %. When I comment out the timer3's code, the application runs fine for a long time and never crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your timer3 a class member or a local variable?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not with the timer, but in `downloadLog()`?

Comment: Which namespace does Timer class you use belong to?

Comment: namespace WindowsFormsApplication1. timer3 is a class variable initiated in class constructor.

Comment: @Krzysiek I think Nikola was wondering about which [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) you were using.

Comment: Sorry. I am using System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` you should expect this kind of behavior. Although this class gives you illusion that it performs operations asynchronously, it's actually using UI thread to do actual work. For that reason, if logic executed by your timer gets stuck, your UI will too.

---

To alleviate this you should use timer which actually does work on a background thread, or alternatively a `BackgroundWorker`.

There are three `Timer` classes within .NET BCL.

1. [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)
2. [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx)
3. [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)

Best fit for your needs is [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) (discussion about this would be rather long. For more information it's best that you read [MSDN Magazine article comparing these three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)).

What you also need to know when doing your work asynchronously and updating UI is that you can't/shouldn't access UI directly from worker thread. Take a look at [SO question regarding this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170448/how-to-invoke-an-ui-method-from-another-thread).