# C# Windows Form application Error : "Cross-thread operation not valid."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to build a simple windows form application in C#. where `lblIPAddress` show my local IP address and `lblInfo`shows my last updated time of my IP address.`btnRefresh` is use to refresh the data. But as soon as `tickTimer_Elapsed` event fired it throws the error "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblInfo' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Please suggest. My complete code has shown below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using Time = System.Timers;
using Connect = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface;

namespace ShowMyIP
{
    public class UpdatedInfo
    {
        public string lastUpdate = string.Empty;
        public string localIP = string.Empty;
    }
    public partial class ShowLocalIP : Form
    {
        UpdatedInfo updatedIP;
        public static Time.Timer tickTimer = new Time.Timer();
        public const int INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;

        public ShowLocalIP()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeTimer();

            updatedIP = new UpdatedInfo();
            updatedIP = GetLocalIP(updatedIP);
            lblIPAddress.Text = updatedIP.localIP;
            lblInfo.Text = updatedIP.lastUpdate;             
        }
        public void InitializeTimer()
        {
            tickTimer.Interval = INTERVAL;
            tickTimer.Enabled = true;
            tickTimer.Elapsed += new Time.ElapsedEventHandler(tickTimer_Elapsed);
            tickTimer.Start();
            GC.KeepAlive(tickTimer);
        }

        private void tickTimer_Elapsed(object sender, Time.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            updatedIP = new UpdatedInfo();
            updatedIP = GetLocalIP(updatedIP);
            lblIPAddress.Text = updatedIP.localIP;
            lblInfo.Text = updatedIP.lastUpdate;           
            tickTimer.Interval = INTERVAL;
            tickTimer.Enabled = true;
            tickTimer.Start();
            GC.KeepAlive(tickTimer);
        }

        private UpdatedInfo GetLocalIP(UpdatedInfo UpdatedIP)
        {
            if (Connect.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                IPHostEntry host;
                host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

                foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
                {
                    if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    {
                        UpdatedIP.localIP = ip.ToString();
                        UpdatedIP.lastUpdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                UpdatedIP.localIP = "127.0.0.1";
                UpdatedIP.lastUpdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();                
            }
            return UpdatedIP;
        }

        private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updatedIP = new UpdatedInfo();
            updatedIP = GetLocalIP(updatedIP);
            lblIPAddress.Text = updatedIP.localIP;
            lblInfo.Text = updatedIP.lastUpdate;             
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thank you. But i am not using any thread concept here.

Comment: The Timer runs on its own thread.  So yes, you *are* using a thread... concept.

Comment: @Peter I am sorry. I missed that. I forgot actually. Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead of System.Timers.Timer? System.Windows.Forms.Timer is designed to avoid this class o problems.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "Invoke" your operation on the UI from the Timer thread.  Cross-thread calls on a Winforms UI are not allowed without an Invoke call.

[How to invoke a UI method from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170448/how-to-invoke-an-ui-method-from-another-thread)