# How to close Form.ShowDialog from another thread and then display second Form.

Tags: c#, winforms

What I'm trying to achieve is to **show** FirstForm during long operation.
When this operation ends I'd like to **close** FirstForm and **show** SecondForm.
Below is sample code: for my suprise Close is not working (both forms are visible).

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new FormMain());
    }
}

class FormMain : Form
{
    public FormMain()
    {
        var button = new Button() { Text = "test" };
        button.Click += (o, e) =>
        {
            var first = new FormFirst();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ////some long operation...
            }).ContinueWith(t => {
                first.Close();
                var second = new FormSecond();
                second.ShowDialog();
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            first.ShowDialog();
        };

        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}

class FormFirst : Form
{
    public FormFirst() { Text = "First"; }
}

class FormSecond : Form
{
    public FormSecond() { Text = "Second"; }
}
}
```

I solved this using Form.Invoke but is this a proper way?:

```
var first = new FormFirst();
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   ////some long operation...
   var created = new AutoResetEvent(first.IsHandleCreated);
   first.HandleCreated += (o1,e1) => created.Set();
   created.WaitOne();
   first.Invoke(new Action(() => first.Close()));
}).ContinueWith(t =>
{
    first.Close();
    var second = new FormSecond();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `invoke` is the proper way to do it.

Since WinForms controls are not thread safe, [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.checkforillegalcrossthreadcalls.aspx) property was added to ensure that the only thread that can access a form's methods is the one it was created by. If the property is set to true, then calling a form's method directly from another thread does not work. Now, you *could* set it to false and go on with your life, however be aware that this exists for very good reasons.

Using `Form.Invoke` is the correct, thread-safe way to do what you're trying to achieve. If you want further explanation, you can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page on creating thread-safe calls to WinForms controls. Also, if you're interested in finding out *why* its like this, user [Adriano Repetti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1207195/adriano-repetti) explained it really well in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10170699/7662085) answer.