# Correct use of using with Timer (or any object where using is relevant)

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

present code is currently structured as follows:

```
System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

public void FirstMethod() {
  myTimer;= new System.Timers.Timer();
  myTimer.start();
  SecondMethod();
}

public void SecondMethod(){
  //several things happen here and then
  myTimer.stop();  
}
```

I've been advised that I could use `using` to correctly garbage collect the Timer object. So I've tried to apply something like the following to my code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475763/is-it-necessary-to-dispose-system-timers-timer-if-you-use-one-in-your-applicatio)):

```
using (SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass())
{  
someClass.DoSomething();  
}
```

I assume the following will error because `myTimer` is not known by `SecondMethod()`?

```
public void FirstMethod() {
  using (System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer())   
  { 
  myTimer.start();
  SecondMethod();
  }
}

public void SecondMethod(){
//several things happen here and then
myTimer.stop();  
}
```

Comment: Why does SecondMethod need to know about myTimer? The dispose will stop the timer.

Comment: IIRC, `using` doesn't take care of garbage collection, it just calls `Dispose` in the object. So unless there is actually a resource that the timer uses, there's no real benefit in `using`.

Comment: @KenWayneVanderLinde correct, dispose does no GC work (except for marshalled data specific to that class).

Comment: @payo ...I'm new to c# and what you've said is effectively my question.

Comment: @whytheq: Really?  Because that's not what you have asked.  If you need to know the difference between managed and native resource management there are many threads about it on SO already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrap an object that implements the `IDisposable` interface in a `using` block when it makes sense to do so.  In this case it does not because the object must be valid at a higher scope.  Remember, a `using` statement is just shorthand (syntactic sugar) for this:

```
var myDisposableObj = new Whatever();
try
{
    // use myDisposableObj.  If an exception is thrown
    // in here somewhere the call to Dispose() still occurs.
}
finally
{
    myDisposableObj.Dispose();
}
```

In your case you need to ensure that you call `Dispose()` on the object when you are done with it (and in a manner that accounts for exceptions which may be thrown that would prevent the call to `Dispose()` from taking place).  You need the `Timer` to stick around for a while, so a `using` block is out of the question.

Comment: System.Threading.Timer does implement IDisposable - maybe whatever @whytheq is trying to accomplish could take advantage of it?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/saba8ksx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @EdS. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475763/is-it-necessary-to-dispose-system-timers-timer-if-you-use-one-in-your-applicatio) seemed to suggest that it is IDisposable

Comment: `Timer` inherits from `Component` which implements `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only use `using` if the object should be disposed (=destroyed) after the `using` block ends. A timer usually lasts longer than that (as in your example).

Answer (score 1):

`using` can only be used on an object that implements `IDisposable` and it will automatically be disposed at the end of the using block. If you need to use that object anywhere else, then you cannot use `using`.

In your example, not only will your original object not be known in other methods, but it'll be deleted.

Comment: In the full code `secondMethod` is actually a method which is subscribed to one of the Timer's events - there is a conditional statement in `secondMethod` and the `Timer`can be stopped under certainconditions

Comment: Why not simply add the timer component to your form? (Is this a WebForm app?) I'm not sure why you are creating the control dynamically when you can simply turn it on and off. Note: I use `using` all the time and like it, but the restrictions described above means I can't use it anywhere.

Comment: it's a windows form. From what I've read System.Timers.Timer does everything that the forms Timer does and more - so I'm using that. Thanks for the help - I'm just playing around getting familiar with various objects

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. Your code is wrong because myTimer is declared as a local variable and it's only available in the *using* scope. You should change your code to sth. like this

```
public void FirstMethod() {
  using (System.Timers.Timer myTimer = new System.Timers.Timer())   
  { 
  myTimer.start();
  SecondMethod(myTimer);
  }
}

public void SecondMethod(System.Timers.Timer theTimer){
    //several things happen here and then
    theTimer.stop();  
}
```

Comment: Dan suggested this below Michael and got shouted at!

Comment: This is just goofy code as it doesn't even use the timer in any reasonable fashion.

Comment: @EdS. my last post in another [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170448/introducing-timer-means-its-multi-threaded) has the full code. You can see in the `keepingTime()` method I've attempted to use using...but this thread has confirmed I'll need to find a different approach

Answer (score 1):

The "using pattern" is used to automatically call Dispose when the implementing object is no longer in scope.  Dispose is used to clean up any unmanaged resources.  Finalize is what the garbage collector calls before the object is "collected".

You could try to "force" collection, however -

> "It is possible to force garbage collection by calling Collect, but most of the time, this should be avoided because it may create performance issues."

So you need SecondMethod to have "access" to myTimer?

Comment: exactly Kris - SecondMethod is actually a method which a Timer event is subscribed to. But if certain contitions are true then SecondMethod should stop the Timer. All that bit works but now I'm trying to make sure the garbage gets collected ok and am looking for alternatives