# C# Old timer overlap the new

Tags: c#, timer, overlap

I have a small game with a timer, when a new match is started the timer must reset, but actually the new timer and the old overlap alternating. I don't understand why.

When a new game start this method it's called:

```
private void setGame()
{
   game = new Game();

   game.gameData.stopWatch = new StopWatch(timerLabel);
   game.gameData.scoreLabel = scoreLabel;
}

public StopWatch(Label timerLabel)
{
   this.timerLabel = timerLabel;

   _timer = new Timer();
   _timer.Interval = 1000;

   _timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
}
```

And then `_timer_Tick` it's called one time with the `startData` of actual match and another time with the `startData` of the old match. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the new instance of `StopWatch`, the old one timer still active.

```
private void setGame()
{
    if (game != null)
        game.gameData.stopWatch.StopTimer();

    game = new Game();

    game.gameData.stopWatch = new StopWatch(timerLabel);
    game.gameData.scoreLabel = scoreLabel;
}
```

and add `StopTimer` function to `StopWatch` class:

```
public StopTimer()
{
    _timer.Stop();
}
```

---

**P.S.** It was a quick fix, just to make the code work. Not necessarily correct from a design point of view. When `System.Timers.Timer`s are used, it might be better to implement `Dispose` pattern. See [Is it necessary to dispose System.Timers.Timer if you use one in your application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/475763)

Comment: I guess no, `StopWatch` is a constructor, not a method.

Comment: @Vitto Just wanted to add that you may consider disposing your old game and timer. The post is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you only call

```
_timer.Tick += new EventHandler(_timer_Tick);
```

once.

Comment: `StopWatch` is not a method. It is the constructor.