# How to create a thread with await methods inside?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm creating a thread

```
Thread MyThread = new Thread(async () => await MyTask());
MyThread.Start();
```

It kinda doesn't make sense and that's the question of how to create it properly.

MyTask is an unending task which periodically starts cpu intensive work

```
async Task MyTask ()
    {
        while (true)
        {                
            await Task.Run(() => CPU_Load());
            await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

CPU_Load is a method where work is being done

```
void CPU_Load ()
    {            
       *CPU_Load*    
    }
```

Comment: Why not use the thread safe [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=net-6.0) instead?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: The question is hot to create a thread? As I've been told the thread class is not aware of async/await, so it executes the method up until it meets the first await and then stops.

Comment: I have never worked with timers, I took a quick look and i dont think its suitable for me.

Comment: @IllSkillz Why isn't a Timer suitable? *"periodically starts cpu intensive work"* - that's what timers do. If you create a thread that runs code, waits, then runs that code again, you've just written your own timer.

Comment: In microsoft example method that is called by the timer delegate is in a different class, and that's the problem because there's global variables that is used by the thread and main code. Also there's an IRC client and Thread is created for each message, I dont think that timer is suitable for that. Is it wrong to use Threads with await inside them? I mean 2 people are suggesting something else...

Comment: How about the original async strategy back when `Main` couldn't be `async`. Start your thread with a non-async function (or delegate or lambda). In that function that simply says `WhatIWantToDoAsync().Wait();` that is async and returns a Task. Your thread function never returns, so waiting for it isn't going to do much.

Comment: *"In microsoft example method that is called by the timer delegate is in a different class"* - That's just the example. It's not a requirement. The timer delegate can be in any class.

Comment: *"Is it wrong to use Threads with await inside them?"* - No, but you're just reinventing a timer.

Comment: That seems to be working! Thanks!

Comment: Ill take a deeper look at timers, thanks

Comment: also a thread works fine with async await.

Comment: Recommended reading; https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread` constructor does not understand `async` delegates. You can read about this here:

- [Is it OK to use "async" with a ThreadStart method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364092/is-it-ok-to-use-async-with-a-threadstart-method)
- [Async thread body loop, It just works, but how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044846/async-thread-body-loop-it-just-works-but-how)

The "proper" way to execute periodically some code depends on where you want to run your code. Do you have any reason to run it on a dedicated thread? Some components are thread-affine, and require to be manipulated by the same thread for the entirety of their existence. If you have this (not very common) requirement, you can use the `Thread` constructor without async/await:

```
var myThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(1000);
        CPU_Load();
        delayTask.Wait();
    }
});
myThread.IsBackground = true;
myThread.Start();
```

Notice how the `Task.Delay` task is created before the CPU-bound operation, and then waited afterwards. This way the interval between two subsequent invocations of the `CPU_Load` method will be constant. It will not depend on the duration of the call itself.

If you don't need a dedicated thread, you can do the work more economically by using reusable threads from the `ThreadPool`. Which is exactly what your current `MyTask` implementation does, with the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method inside. To start the task is as easy as invoking the asynchronous method:

```
var myTask = MyTask();
```

Now the task is running, and will continue running until the process terminates, or the `CPU_Load` invocation fails, whatever comes first.

Another way to implement the asynchronous `MyTask` method would be to wrap the whole loop in a `Task.Run`, instead of having the `Task.Run` inside the loop. Functionally and performance-wise is almost identical:

```
var myTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delayTask = Task.Delay(1000);
        CPU_Load();
        await delayTask;
    }
});
```

I have omitted the `ConfigureAwait(false)` because it's not really needed in this case. The [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) does not have a synchronization context that can be captured by the `await`.

You could also consider using a [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer) to run periodically your work, but in my opinion the `Task`-based approach is superior. It's quite tricky to enforce a non-overlapping execution policy with constant interval using a `Timer`. Caveats:

1. The `System.Timers.Timer` class [is not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#thread-safety).
2. It allows overlapping invocations of the event handler.
3. It [swallows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer#remarks) any exceptions thrown inside the handler.
4. It [is possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.stop#remarks) for the `Elapsed` event to be raised **after** stopping the `Timer` with the `Stop` method.
5. There is no easy way to stop the timer, and then wait for all running event handlers to complete.
6. The class is disposable and [needs to be disposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475763/is-it-necessary-to-dispose-system-timers-timer-if-you-use-one-in-your-applicatio).

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947206/how-to-create-a-thread-with-await-methods-inside/70949587#comment125424587_70947206) by Flydog57:

> How about the original async strategy back when `Main` couldn't be async. Start your thread with a non-async function (or delegate or lambda). In that function that simply says `WhatIWantToDoAsync().Wait();` that is async and returns a Task. Your thread function never returns, so waiting for it isn't going to do much.

Comment: If flydog57's suggestion was helpful then please ask him/her to leave a post so he/she could receive reputation for that.

Comment: This may work as a workaround but Task.Wait blocks the invoking thread, in this case for the whole run of the application. So the newly created thread will only run until first suspend and then block until the while loop ends. You'd be better off doing everything synchronously and using Thread.Sleep. Or use Timer as suggested.